# livewire wire:submit.prevent only works when the form is submitted by submit button

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-livewire

Hello Im using livewire in my new project,
my problem is that I want to execute some js code before submitting the form that has wire:submit.prevent

```
<form id="message_send" wire:submit.prevent="save">
```

I have added a listener for the button and I wan to submit the form after some lines of code and then use livewire functionality.

but  I can't submit the form via Javascript and then get into **save()** backend method

Answer (score 1):

Set the attribute `type="button"` on your button, by default the attribute is on `type="submit"`.

Then at the end of your JS function, send the form with `document.getElementById("message_send").submit()`

Comment: hello, thanks for your attention, but I have tried that, doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

I used a strange solution for my problem ,
I added a submit button to my form and in javascript , after doing some actions that I needed to , I simulate a click on the submit button :)
But I still think this couldn't be the most proper way...